# How to keep Advanced Python Schedular script running?

Tags: python, ubuntu, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I have installed Advanced Python Scheduler and created a small script which has some tasks created in it.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import document
sched = BlockingScheduler()

@sched.scheduled_job('interval', minutes=3)
def timed_job():
    print('This job is run every three minutes.')
    document.add_collection()

@sched.scheduled_job('cron', day_of_week='mon-fri', hour=17)
def scheduled_job():
    print('This job is run every weekday at 5pm.')

sched.start()
```

Now for simple execution i can start the script in terminal using `python clock.py` and it would run fine. But once i close terminal, it's gone.

So, how do i run this script in background? I know for simple tasks `python clock.py &` is a way.

But i need to schedule tasks for a web app and want to keep these tasks running for next 1 year or more.

What are the options available in Ubuntu?

How can i run it as daemon or in background?

Is there a way to keep a check of it's progress?

Comment: You might try supervisor http://supervisord.org/ or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/ or http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/

Comment: @Duikboot python-daemon seems promising. but how do i call the clock.py script in it?